# Drupal: xmlsitemap file is not generated

Tags: drupal, module, sitemap

I have chosen XMLSiteMap module from the most popular usage statistics on Drupal site,
so I assume the module is not too buggy. But the map file is absent.

I've installed this module on my Windows machine into drupal/sites/default/modules.
I've activated all the submodules of XMLSiteMap in admin menu.
Per docs, I've also run cron.php manually to create sitemap.xml in drupal/sites/default/files - but it's just not present there even when second re-install.
**How can I force to create sitemap.xml?**

(also tried with and w/o clean URLs - still no help).

**Also, if there any good reliable alternative for this module?**

Comment: what was the final solution? In the accepted answer, there are just two links without any kind of REAL answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also make sure you have the latest version installed, it just came out yesterday:

http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap

Also, see this issue, seems related to your problem:

http://drupal.org/node/458546

Comment: maybe you should elaborate on this... This answer is accepted, however it doesn't contain any real answers. We can only see two links which don't really help... What's the real SOLUTION to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've installed it properly? Please check the Status report (admin/logs/status in Drupal 5, admin/reports/status in Drupal 6) to ensure that you've got everything right.

It's possible that you haven't set the permissions of sites/default/files properly yet for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but if you are looking for an actual created sitemap.xml file rather than navigating to it in the browser I don't believe one is created by the module. I think the module creates a menu callback to create the sitemap file, so a request for sitemap.xml is handled by Drupal's menu system, rather than creating an actual file. There will however be a cached version in sites/default/files/xmlsitemap.

Apologies if this is an oversimplification of the question asked.

I have not had any problems with the reliability of the module myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably recommend trying the 6.x-2.x branch which I've been rewriting to kind of solve all the annoying bugs and architectural problems of the 6.x-1.x branch. It's currently incomplete, but it works for nodes and menu items currently. Taxonomy terms and user profiles will be added soon.

You can find the link to it on the project page. Sorry I can't link since I'm a new user. :)

Answer (score 0):

Running the CRON worked for me:

`/admin/reports/status/run-cron`